# Displaying CAEAGLLayer in a UIView or CALayer

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, opengl-es, calayer

Rather new to trying to get OpenGL ES working on the iPhone, but I've created a working demo from an OpenGL template and wanted to add it to another App which is a standard UIViewController App. After searching around it seems that I can't addSubview a CAEAGLLayer to a CALayer aka UIView. How would I go about doing this? Or am I completely wrong in what I'm doing.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I actually had to do was change in the EAGLView -initWithCoder to -initWithFrame and make the appropriate changes to the method to handle the frame. Once I did that and initialised the view with initWithFrame it worked.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Been trying to fix it for hours now. Could you please, in detail show how you ended up fixing this? Thank you

Comment: This was so long ago so I'm really pushing it but I was initially had the EAGLView custom class implementing the -initWithCoder method. I instead implemented the -initWithFrame, did all the initialisation required in that method and called that on initialisation.


In a nutshell implement the -initWithFrame instead of the -initWithCoder method.

Comment: well, I moved the code from the initWithCoder to my viewDidLoad, deleted the initwithcoder(), and ofcoz changed things like self.layer to self.view.layer. But the issue I am facing now is that NSStringFromClass([[self.view.layer] class]) is returning a CALayer.      + (Class)layerClass is not getting called because Im using a UIViewController and not UIView. I therefore get the error: [CALayer setDrawableProperties:]: unrecognized selector. i believe I just need to pass this and im done ? Thank you

Comment: Mmm, don't do it in viewDidLoad, do it in initwithframe, I never looked into why but I'm guessing there are some different initialisations in this. Sorry, it was so long ago that having trouble remembering.

Comment: all good now, working fine. I created a UIView sub-class and in its initWithFrame is where I put the code from initWithCoder. I also added the supporting methods. I then added the method + (Class)layerClass to return [CAEAGLLayer class]. In my viewController I alloc init my custom UIView class and all the animations and stuff work now. Will still try your approach and see how that goes. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Simply use a UIView and add:

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

That UIView is now a CAEAGLLayer, so you can add that view as a subview of another UIView like normal.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In swift it is:

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return CAEAGLLayer.self
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for CALayer's insertSublayer methods or the addSublayer method.